# automated install of asp.net mvc 4 for web server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automation

I need to get mvc4 installed from command line / scripts, since the servers will all from an image. Is this possible? Mvc 2 had an msi, and could use msiexec, but as far as I can see that's not feasible with 4.

web platform installer is supposed to be command line friendly, but the actual wpi install doesn't seem to be command line driven. Any ideas for this?